# passing different int value to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, conditional-statements

I am working on an app which needs to pass an int value to a `BroadcastReceiver`.

1. How do I send an value to `BroadcastReceiver`?
2. The int value changes based on a condition. How can I send the value that is stored according to the condition?

Here is my code:

```
switch(item) {
    case 0:
        pro = 0;
        levelDialog.dismiss();
        break;
    case 1:
        pro = 1;      
        levelDialog.dismiss();
        break;
    case 2:
        pro = 2;
        levelDialog.dismiss();
        break;
}
```

pro value changes according to the condition. How can I send this value to `BroadcasteReceiver` and how do I receive it in the `BroadcastReceiver`?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register BroadcastReceiver. When you send broadcast you need to store the int values into Intent and pass that Intent to BroadcastReceiver.

You can try something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Below is the sample code of BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 int pro = intent..getIntExtra("pro", 0);
 Intent service = new Intent(context, WordService.class);
 context.startService(service);
}
}
```

Comment: i tried this way but dont know how to receive it on receiver side:


Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
       intentAlarm.putExtra("pro",pro);